# Trigger to copy the same row into another table

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

How do I get values in Table 1 to Table2; that would duplicate the row based on Table1's column (Orders)

Table1:

```
ID       TICKETID USERNAME FIRSTNAME LASTNAME ORDERS STATUS
SEL00007            Hema1     Hema    Sri       3      New
SEL00008            Romi1     Romi     T        2      New
```

Table2:

```
ID       TICKETID USERNAME FIRSTNAME LASTNAME ORDERS STATUS
SEL00007            Hema1     Hema    Sri       3      New
SEL00007            Hema1     Hema    Sri       3      New
SEL00007            Hema1     Hema    Sri       3      New
SEL00008            Romi1     Romi     T        2      New
SEL00008            Romi1     Romi     T        2      New
```

This is what I was able to come up with after referring to lot of other posts

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER Duplicate_Rows
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON Table1
REFERENCING NEW AS New OLD AS Old
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE N_Ord NUMBER;
BEGIN
N_Ord := (SELECT (Orders) from Table2);
INSERT INTO UserTable2 (TICKETID,username,firstName,lastName,Status)
SELECT :New.TICKETID,:New.username,:New.firstName,:New.lastName,:New.Status
FROM dual
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= N_Ord; 
END Duplicate_Rows;
/
```

Please help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Close; no need to separately select `orders` into a variable; it'll fail anyway because table is mutating so trigger can't see it.

Trigger:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg_ai_t1 AFTER
  2    INSERT ON table1
  3    FOR EACH ROW
  4  BEGIN
  5    INSERT INTO table2(
  6      id,
  7      ticketid,
  8      username,
  9      firstname,
 10      lastname,
 11      orders,
 12      status
 13    )
 14      SELECT :new.id,
 15             :new.ticketid,
 16             :new.username,
 17             :new.firstname,
 18             :new.lastname,
 19             :new.orders,
 20             :new.status
 21      FROM dual CONNECT BY
 22        level <= :new.orders;
 23
 24  END;
 25  /

Trigger created.
```

Insert into `table1`:

```
SQL> INSERT INTO table1(
  2    id,
  3    ticketid,
  4    username,
  5    firstname,
  6    lastname,
  7    orders,
  8    status
  9  )VALUES(
 10    'SEL00007',
 11    NULL,
 12    'Hema1',
 13    'Hema',
 14    'Sri',
 15    3,
 16    'New'
 17  );

1 row created.
```

Result:

```
SQL> SELECT *
  2  FROM table1;

ID           TICKETID USERNAME   FIRST LASTN     ORDERS STATU
---------- ---------- ---------- ----- ----- ---------- -----
SEL00007              Hema1      Hema  Sri            3 New

SQL> SELECT *
  2  FROM table2;

ID           TICKETID USERNAME   FIRST LASTN     ORDERS STATU
---------- ---------- ---------- ----- ----- ---------- -----
SEL00007              Hema1      Hema  Sri            3 New
SEL00007              Hema1      Hema  Sri            3 New
SEL00007              Hema1      Hema  Sri            3 New

SQL>
```

Comment: Thanks so much, @Littlefoot!! It's working as expected....I have been on it for over an hour. :|